# CSP issues with facebook messenger-checkbox in an Iframe

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-messenger

I want to provide my users the ability to add the [Facebook checkbox plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/checkbox-plugin) to their website through an iframe.

My application provides the iframe and hosts the page:

```
<iframe src="https://www.botletter.com/cif/GWoe6LUboG9YBrdudAA2naV5" style="border:none;width:100%;"></iframe>
```

And then people add this iframe to their website. I whitelist their website's domain name and put their domain name as origin:

```
<div class="fb-messenger-checkbox"
  origin="<%= @checkbox.website %>"
  page_id="<%= @core_bot.page_id %>"
  messenger_app_id="MY APP ID"
  user_ref="<%= @random_user_ref %>"
  prechecked="false"
  allow_login="true"
  size="<%= @checkbox.button_size %>"></div>
```

Unfortunately, it does not render and I get the following error:

> Refused to display
>   'https://www.facebook.com/v2.6/plugins/messenger_checkbox.php?allow_login=true&app_id=534768046912528&channel=https%3A%2F%2Fstaticxx.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter%2Fr%2FlY4eZXm_YWu.js%3Fversion%3D42%23cb%3Df2218eaf474e464%26domain%3Dwww.botletter.com%26origin%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.botletter.com%252Ff1ea0c055b4547%26relation%3Dparent.parent&container_width=689&locale=en_US&messenger_app_id=534768046912528&origin=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.lalanguefrancaise.com%2F&page_id=1115924038427162&prechecked=true&sdk=joey&size=small&user_ref=437aa962df71ec4eea67'
>   in a frame because an ancestor violates the following Content Security
>   Policy directive: "frame-ancestors https://www.lalanguefrancaise.com".

The error bellow can be reproduced [on this page](https://www.lalanguefrancaise.com/orthographe/nul-part-ou-nulle-part/).

Maybe this is caused because I render the checkbox in an iframe that I integrate in another website? Do you have any idea how I can make this work?

Comment: Because of iframeception, it's not possible to do this. I used an inline javascript snippet instead.

Comment: can you explain what you did to get it to work? we are facing the same issue -- trying to display the send to messenger checkbox in our iframe on a customers domain, but it does not appear.

Comment: I injected some javascript in order to trigger the Facebook script. So you need to add the script line and then the iframe.

Comment: Running into a similar issue for me as well. We are providing a plugin for multiple dealership websites that renders us inside an iframe modal. We want to get the checkbox plugin to work, but it fails even though we whitelisted everything correctly ? This seems a reasonable use case for this. Were you able to fix that ?

Comment: What I did is to add the js script with the iframe, not in the iframe ;)

Comment: I ran into the same issue when rendering my custom plugin in an iframe in another site. @AlphaNico can you share sample snippet on how you did what you had said?

Comment: @AlphaNico I also would like to see the code snippet.